# Detect a keypress inside of a three.js scene using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, three.js, keydown

I am trying to detect a keypress inside of a scene that is a div with the id "world" I have this code which I think **should** work but it does not. Here it is:

```js
$('world').keyup(function(e){
    console.log('keyup');
    if(e.keyCode == 46 || 8) {
        if(selectedWood != null){
            array.splice(index, object.findIndex(selectedWood));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is you need '#' to select an element with ID, so $('#world') instead of ('world').

The second issue is e.keyCode will work on some browsers but not all. Since you're using jQuery, you can reliably use e.which:

```
if(e.which == 46 || e.which == 8)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (e.which == 46 || e.which == 8)`? 8 will always evaluate to truthy.

Answer (score 0):

As your viewport div can't be focussed (unlike a text input field), your method won't detect any `keyup`. Instead you need to attach the event listener to `window`:

```js
$(window).keyup(function (event) {
    ...
});
```

If you have any `<input>` fields or `<textarea>` elements on your webpage, you probably don't wan't to listen to these 3d scene specific events while entering text. So, you might want to extend the code:

```js
$(window).keyup(function (event) {
    if(['INPUT', 'TEXTAREA'].indexOf(event.target.tagName) !== -1) return;
    ...
});
```